# Redirect non-existing subpage to another page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I would like to redirect:

domainname.com/instalator (non existing) to domainname.com/install

using .htaccess. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /instalator /install
```

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?instalator(/.*)$ /install$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you have other rewrite rules that map `/install` to a resource or some sort of router, then you'll need to stick with mod_rewrite and **you must place the above rule *before* any of your routing rules**.